# Tailwindcss in webpack configuration not getting applied

Tags: javascript, webpack, tailwind-css

In developping an outlook add-in.

I would add tailwind to it, here's [the tuto](https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/1c93938c1fe4f10d1e5b0532ae22e16a) that I'm following

In **package.json** I get these scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "dev-server": "webpack serve --mode development",
     ...
  },
```

then in **webpack.config.js**

```
const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      vendor: ["react", "react-dom", "core-js", "@fluentui/react"],
      taskpane: ["react-hot-loader/patch", "./src/taskpane/index.tsx", "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html"],
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.ts",
    },
    output: {
      clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          include: '/src',
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-typescript"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ["react-hot-loader/webpack", "ts-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
          type: "asset/resource",
          generator: {
            filename: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      ...
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["taskpane", "vendor", "polyfills"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "commands.html",
        template: "./src/commands/commands.html",
        chunks: ["commands"],
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Promise: ["es6-promise", "Promise"],
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      server: {
        type: "https",
        options: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
      },
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
    },
  };
```

In **postcss.config.js**:

```
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'postcss-preset-env',
    tailwindcss
  ],
};
```

and finally the **tailwind.config.js**

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./dist/*.html'],
    theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

When I try to apply a tailwind css class nothing is happening , and also when I check in devTools if tailwind css colors tokens are imported for exemple I don't see anything.

I import tailwind components in index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Then webpack generates me these imports in taskpane.html

```
<link href="bd3fc3e614edb4896e6a.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script defer="defer" src="vendor.js"></script>
<script defer="defer" src="taskpane.js"></script>
```

When I run my app using `npm run dev-server`
I don't see the classes get applied to html.

I think that tailwind is not importing them in css file

[image]

Here's my project folders configuration :

[image]

Don't hesitate if you want to see other files contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tailwind.config.js`, the `content` should point the paths from `src` folder.

That's because, as stated in the [official docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation), Tailwind CSS works by scanning all source files (HTML files, JavaScript components, and any other templates) for class names, generating the corresponding styles and then writing them to a static CSS file.

Webpack builds, in a single process, both styles and JS files, and then it writes these files in the `dist` folder.
Pointing to the `dist` folder in `tailwind.config.js` won't work because, at build time, the `dist` folder is not yet updated.

Assuming that you would use Tailwind classes in React files (`ts`, `tsx`), but also in `html` files, the followind config should work:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{ts,tsx,html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And `index.tsx` should be:

```
import React from "react";
import './index.css';
```

Webpack config:

```
...
module: {
  rules: [
    ...
    {
      test: /\.css$/i,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
    },
    ...
  ]
}
...
```

---

The tutorial that you were following is pointing to the `dist` folder because it contains the `index.html` file - which is actually a manually created file and is not part of the build process - it is updated manually.

The tutorial will only work for Tailwind classes that are written in `index.html`.

Since you are using `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, with the `template` option, the source `html` files are included in the build process and then written in the `dist` folder.

Actually you can check that - in the setup created following that tutorial and also if not using a plugin that completely cleans the dist folder before the build - when running the build for the second time, Tailwind finds some classes in the files from the previous build and will generate css accordingly - as stated in the this [comment](https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/1c93938c1fe4f10d1e5b0532ae22e16a?permalink_comment_id=4492328#gistcomment-4492328).

---

A more comprehensive tutorial is:

https://dev.to/ivadyhabimana/setup-tailwind-css-in-a-react-project-configured-from-scratch-a-step-by-step-guide-2jc8

Comment: thanks that's working , juste to know , in which cases we point tailwind.config to `dist` folder and sometimes to `src` ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tutorial you posted you need to do this instead inside your dist/index.html

```html
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

The style.css needs to be imported inside index.js file.

Just pointing out what is on the tutorial, not sure if that tutorial is valid though.

Comment: I'm doing it already : `<script defer="defer" src="taskpane.js"></script>`but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

`tailwind.config.js` should be

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

in `app.js`

```
import "./index.css";
```

everything else seems correct

Make sure you installed "postcss","postcss-loader" and "postcss-preset-env",

Answer (score 0):

ok,so easy.

Follow as this: [tailwind.config.js]

```js
  content: ['./src/**/**.{html,js}'],
```